# C++ printing contents of array that was declared in main

Tags: c++, arrays, class, io

working on program where an array has to be declared in the main (in this case, `distList[5]`) and it has to be sent to one member where it has to be filled by user input (`inputDist`) and then sent to another member from there (`printAndAdd`) to be printed and added, as suggested by the name. I believe I've gotten the array filled, but I'm not sure how to go from there. any help is appreciated.

```
void CDistance::inputDist(CDistance distList[], int size)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter 5 digits following each one with a space to place into the array: " << endl;
        int ui1;    cin >> ui1;
        int ui2;    cin >> ui2;
        int ui3;    cin >> ui3;
        int ui4;    cin >> ui4;
        int ui5;    cin >> ui5;
        distList[i] = CDistance(ui1, ui2, ui3, ui4, ui5);
        cout << distList;

    }
}

void CDistance::printAndAdd(const CDistance distList[], int size)
{
    //cout << distList;
}

int main()
{
    CDistance distList[5];

    CDistance d1, d2(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    d1.setDistt();
    d1.printDistt();
    d1.menu(d2);
    d1.inputDist(distList, 5);
    d1.printAndAdd(distList, 5);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Also, here is the class definition of CDistance:

```
class CDistance
{
private:
    int feet;
    int inches;
    int feet2;
    int inches2;
    int five;

public:
    CDistance();
    CDistance(int, int, int, int, int);
    ~CDistance();
    void setDistt();
    void printDistt() const;
    void add(const CDistance&) const;
    void subtract(const CDistance&) const;
    void menu(const CDistance&) const;
    void inputDist(CDistance distList[], int size);
    void printAndAdd(const CDistance distList[], int size);
};

CDistance::CDistance()
{
    feet = 0;
    inches = 0;
    feet2 = 0;
    inches2 = 0;
    five = 0;
}

CDistance::CDistance(int f, int i, int f2, int i2, int fi)
{
    feet = f;
    inches = i;
    feet2 = f2;
    inches2 = i2;
    five = fi;
}

CDistance::~CDistance()
{
}
```

Comment: The first help you need is to understand the difference between a function and a class method: "...one function where it has to be filled by user input (inputDist)". Your inputDist() is not a function, it's a class method. "...and then sent to another function from there (printAndAdd)". printAndAdd() is not a function either. It is also a class method. You need to start over, spend some time learning the difference between functions and class methods, and then you can try this again.

Comment: The posted code can be improved in many different places. It's hard to suggest any particular thing since you haven't asked a specific question. This site is not about generic code review.

Comment: I'm trying to print out the contents of `distlist[5]` that was filled in the class member `inputDist`. @RSahu

Comment: OK. What's the question?

Comment: How would I go about that? When I try a for loop, trying to print the contents, it gives me the error of "No operator '<<' matches these operands." I did try and create an operator overload of << but wasn't sure how to execute it. @RSahu

Comment: If you "did try and create an operator overload" of <<, but it didn't work, then this would be a valid question to ask: "here's how I did it, why doesn't it work?" But what do you expect here: just make a declaration that "it didn't work", and expect someone else to write it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you said:

> How would I go about that? When I try a for loop, trying to print the contents, it gives me the error of "No operator '<<' matches these operands." I did try and create an operator overload of << but wasn't sure how to execute it.

Declare `operator>>` and `operator<<` overloads to allow you read a `CDistance` from a stream and write a `CDistance` to a stream.

```
class CDistance;
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, CDistance& distance);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, CDistance const& distance);
```

Make them `friend`s of the class.

```
class CDistance
{

   ...

   friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, CDistance& distance);
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, CDistance const& distance);

};
```

Implement them.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, CDistance& d)
{
   return (is >> d.feet >> d.inches >> d.feet2 >> d.inches2 >> d.five);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, CDistance const& distance);
{
   // Add a space between the members when writing it out.
   return (is << d.feet << " " << d.inches << " "
              << d.feet2 << " " << d.inches2 << " " << d.five);
}
```

Now you can use

```
Distance d;
std::cin >> d;
std::cout << d << std::endl;
```

I suggest the following additional improvements:

You don't need `inputDist` and `printAndAdd` to be member functions of the class since they don't need access to `private` members of the class. They can be non-member functions.

```
void inputDist(CDistance distList[], int size)
{
   // for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) // Use size, not 1
   {
      cout << "Please enter 5 digits following each one with a space to place into the array: " << endl;
      cin >> distList[i];
      cout << distList << endl;
   }
}

void printAndAdd(const CDistance distList[], int size)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      cout << distList[i] << std::endl;
      // Not sure what "Add" means to you.
   }
}
```

Comment: I deleted my previous comment as I answered my own question. Thank you for your help! I am a beginner to C++ and this operation overloading stuff to me is very confusing.

Comment: what are the chances you could help me with the addition overload? This is what I've done this far:
    `class CDistance
CDistance& operator+ (CDistance& add, CDistance& distance);`


    
`CDistance& operator+ (CDistance& add, CDistance& di)
{
 int add = di.feet + di.inches + di.feet2 + di.inches2 + di.five;
 return add;
}`

I know this looks like absolute garbage. I'm not sure if there is any other way I could clean this up?

Comment: @JustinFarr, don't make this a free consulting session :) Grab a textbook and read up on the fundamentals of operator overloads.